# Recognize the Host App in an iOS8 Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

How do I recognize in which host app my keyboard is running?

Basically, I want to change some things in my custom keyboard in specific apps

Maybe I can customize the keyboard traits to my use?

Thanks

Comment: It is my problem too. I want to detect if it running in app that is not optimized for iphone 6 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945373/how-to-detect-if-ios8-custom-keyboard-extension-is-running-in-not-iphone-6-optim

Comment: Looking for this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125299/ios8-custom-keyboard-detect-which-app-is-using-keyboard

Comment: This might be an invitation to build a private framework for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless it is one of your own app, or you have some kind of collaboration with the running app.

A custom keyboard and a running app can communicate with Darwin notification. The running apps needs to broadcast the darwin notification, and keyboard needs to observe that. So if the developer is not already broadcasting it, then you can't identify it.

Comment: can you explain more about the darwin notifications?