# iOS8 Custom Keyboard: Detect which app is using keyboard

Tags: keyboard, uikeyboard, ios8-extension

I made a custom iOS8 keyboard but I need to detect which app is using the keyboard.

f.e. I need to know if its `Whatsapp` or just normal `Messages` to handle a different logic.

I haven't found any related question on this. And frankly I don't think this is possible, or even allowed by Apple.

The closest other Q/A I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675628/how-to-detect-whether-custom-keyboard-is-activated-from-the-keyboards-container).